# Prove $A−(A−B) = A\cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have already proved that $A-(A-B) = A \cap B$. The problem is that I cant find a way to get $A-(A-B)$ from $A \cap B$

$A ∩ B = x \in A \wedge  x \in B
      = (x \in A \wedge  x \in A) \wedge (x \in B \wedge  x \in A)
      = (x \in A) \wedge (x \in A ∩ B)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $A-(A-B)=A \cap B$ by use set properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913409/prove-that-a-a-b-a-cap-b-by-use-set-properties)

Comment: @huzaifaabedeen No, that is the part (i already have it), now i need to prove the reverse ( starting from A ∩ B to A - ( A - B )

Comment: I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2552118), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2472458), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728604).

Comment: What is needed is a general method of attack, for problems of this nature.  Given two sets, $S$ and $T$, to show that $S = T$ you show that $S \subseteq T$ and that $T \subseteq S.$  In order to do this, you show that $\{x \in  S ~[\text{somehow}]~ \implies x \in T\}$ and that $\{x \in  T ~[\text{somehow}]~ \implies x \in S\}.$

Comment: "I have already proved that A−(A−B)=A∩B"  Then what more needs to be done?  "The problem is that I cant find a way to get A−(A−B) from A∩B"  Then how did you prove A−(A−B)=A∩B?

Comment: $=$ sign is an equal sign.  It means the two are the same thing.  If you have proven $A-(A-B) = A\cap B$ that goes both ways.  It means that $A-(A-B)$ and $A\cap B$ are the same thing.  And "$A\cap B = A-(A-B)$" and "$A-(A-B) = A\cap B$" are both equivalent statements and mean the exact same thing.... Have you actually proven that $A-(A-B)$ is the same set as $A\cap B$? Or do you mean to say that you have only proven that $A-(A-B)$ is a *subset* of $A\cap B$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$A\cap B=\phi \cup (A\cap B)=(A\cap A^C)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap (A^c\cup B)=A\cap(A\cap B^c)^c=A-(A\cap B^c)=A-(A-B)$$

Comment: OP is able to prove this , he wants to go backwards

Comment: See it again. Just reverse the steps.

Comment: @LalitTolani: This is the complete proof, and proves that the sets are **equal**.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I know it is but the thing is that it can be done by OP also as it has been provided by Huzaifa Abedeen in above links, something new must be shared (as you did) I believe

Comment: @LalitTolani This is the direction that was asked. Look at the second sentence. " The problem is that I cant find a way to get A−(A−B) from A∩B".

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A\cap B$. Then, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. This implies $x\notin A-B$ (think why?). Now, $x\in A$ and $x\notin A-B$, implying $x\in A-(A-B)$. This proves the second part.

---

Or alternatively, as other answers have written, you can directly prove both parts into one by set algebra:
$$A\cap B=\emptyset \cup (A\cap B)$$
$$=(A\cap A')\cup (A\cap B)$$
and then use the distributive property and the fact that $A-B$ is defined to be $A\cap B'$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B$ contains all elements of $A$ except for those in $A$ that are not elements of $B$.

$\ldots$   Thus $A\cap B\subseteq A\smallsetminus(A\smallsetminus B)$.

$A\smallsetminus(A\smallsetminus B)$ contains elements that are in $A$ that are also either in $B$ or not in $A$.

$\ldots$   Thus $A\smallsetminus (A\smallsetminus B)\subseteq A\cap B$.

$${\begin{align}A\smallsetminus (A\smallsetminus B)&= A\cap(A\cap B^\complement)^\complement\\&=\phantom{A\cap(A^\complement\cup B)}\\&=\phantom{A\cap A^\complement)\cup(A\cap B)}\\&= A\cap B\end{align}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap B= A\cup B-(A-B)-(B-A)= A\cup B-(B-A)-(A-B)=$

$(A\cup B-(B-A))-(A-B)=(A\cup B\cap(B\cap A')')-(A-B)=$

$((A\cup B)\cap(B'\cup A))-(A-B)=$

$(A\cup(B\cap B'))-(A-B)=(A\cup \phi)-(A-B)=A-(A-B)$

Answer (score -1):

$A\cap B = (A\cap B)\cup \phi =(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap\lnot A)=A\cap(\lnot A\cup B)=A\cap\lnot(A\cap\lnot B)=A-(A-B)$

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I think it was correct.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala It is correct. I seem to have a "fan".